# Getting error for converting IBinder to ISurface in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

We are getting error in converting from IBinder to ISurface.

The code used to convert is,

```
interface_cast<ISurface>(data.readStrongBinder());
```

Error is, "`undefined reference to`android::ISurface::asInterface(android::sp const&)'`"

Kindly help.
ABS

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but maybe will help someone.
I had similar issue, but with converting this way:

```
interface_cast<IAudioFlinger>(binder);
```

Solution was to include libmedia in Android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \ 
    libmedia
```

In your case, it should be some library from surface.